# How to call GameObject positions in the scene

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently generating a set amount of GameObjects in code. What is the best way to call the plane positions in a loop where I can get the positions of each plane to guarantee the walls spawning within them?

```
public class LevelGenerator: MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshSurface surface;
    private float[,] positionX = { {-9.5f, 9f}, {12f, 30f}, {12f, 30f}};
    private float[,] positionZ = {{9f, -9.5f}, {9f, -9.5f}, { 11.5f,30f}};  
    public GameObject wall;

    void OnEnable(){
        GenerateMaze();

        surface.BuildNavMesh();
    }

    void GenerateMaze(){
    //For every plane 
        for (int i = 0; i<=2  ; i++){    
        //Place some walls on that plane  
            for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
            {       
                Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(positionX[i,0], positionX[i,1]), 0.5f, Random.Range(positionZ[i,0], positionZ[i,1])); 
                Instantiate(wall, pos, Quaternion.identity, transform);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you want to store these objects and access them later? Do you just want to access the object you instantiate? I added a snippet in case the data you want is stored within the script of what you are instantiating. Once you clear up exactly what you want I can edit my response.

Comment: Basically I want to instantiate x amount of cubes at random location within the 3 planes if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GetComponent`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.GetComponent.html) when `Instantiating` your objects. After that, you can either store them or mutate them however you like. There are also other functions such as [`GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html) and [`FindObjectsOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html). I would only use these if you absolutely need and do not use them in functions called often like `Update`. Any of the `Find` methods come with a decent amount of overhead.

I am unsure of what your script is called that you want to access on your objects, so I will fill it in with `YourScriptHere`.

```
// if you want to store the objects, creat a list to reference them
private List<YourScriptHere> yourScripts = new List<YourScriptHere>();

void GenerateMaze(){
//For every plane 
    for (int i = 0; i<=2  ; i++){    
    //Place some walls on that plane  
        for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++)
        {       
            Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(positionX[i,0], positionX[i,1]), 0.5f, Random.Range(positionZ[i,0], positionZ[i,1]));
            
            YourScriptHere tmpScript = Instantiate(wall, pos, Quaternion.identity, transform).GetComponent<YourSciptHere>();
            
            // mutate the data in tmpScript however you like
            tmpScript.FunctionCall(data);
            
            // if you want to track and store the data, then add it to a list for further processing later
            yourScripts.Add(tmpScript);
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want the position, you can just access the instantiated object and grab its `Transform`, then access the `position`. If you want to access objects by position later and you are storing the positions, you can make a `<Vector3, GameObject>` `Dictionary`.

Comment: Thank you sir. I've used FindAllGameObjectswithTag and gave the 3 platforms specific tag now I am just trying to figure out how to make my 2nd foreach loop instantiate exactly 10 cubes on each platform.

Basically this line of code needs to be changed: 
Vector3 pos = new Vector3(Random.Range(positionX[i,0], positionX[i,1]), 0.5f, Random.Range(positionZ[i,0], positionZ[i,1]));

Comment: You can child the cubes to each plane, then just randomize only two axes. The cubes will then be offsets from each plane

Comment: i made a second forloop to iterate between xnumber of walls and i instantiate each one within the boundaries of 3 platforms. thanks for ur help!